# How to get the vip package to work with an mlr model in R?

Tags: r, mlr

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here... but I'm trying to use an `mlr` package created model with the `vip` package in `R`. Specifically, im trying to use the `vint` function from the `vip` package to calculate the 2-way interaction strength between variables. Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
library(mlr)
library(vip)
library(randomForest)


# Get example data
airQ <- data.frame(airquality)
airQ <- na.omit(airQ)

# Set up mlr model
airQ_task  <- makeRegrTask(data = airQ, target = "Ozone")
airQ_lrn <- makeLearner("regr.randomForest")
airQ_mod <- train(airQ_lrn, airQ_task)

# For comparison set up randomForest model
aqFit <- randomForest(Ozone~., data = airQ)

# Use vip to get variable interaction
vint(aqFit, feature_names = c("Solar.R", "Temp")) # rf model works
vint(airQ_mod, feature_names = c("Solar.R", "Temp")) # mlr model does not work
```

Using the code above, the `vint` function works for the `randomForest` model but does not work with the `mlr` model. Instead, for the `mlr` model, it throws back an error saying:

> Error in get_training_data.default(object) :    The training data
>   could not be extracted from object. Please supply the raw training
>   data using the `train` argument in the call to `partial`.

I think that the `vip` package was updated recently and they have changed how some functions work... but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I also know that the `vip` package does accept `mlr` models because if I try to use the `vip` variable importance function, everything works fine? e.g.,

```
vip(airQ_mod)
```

Any suggestions as to how I would make the `vint` function work with `mlr`?

Answer (score 2):

`mlr` returns a wrapped model; you need to get the underlying R model. The `getLearnerModel()` function is provided for this purpose:

```
vint(getLearnerModel(airQ_mod), feature_names = c("Solar.R", "Temp"))
```

...however, the `pdp` package (used by `vip` internally) does some "magic" to get to the original training data, which isn't compatible with how mlr trains its models. You'll have to supply the training data explicitly I'm afraid, as suggested by the error message.

Comment: Sorry, that took some digging into the source code of various packages -- unfortunately the way the data is retrieved is incompatible with how `mlr` trains models.

Comment: Oh interesting.... That answers that!! Thanks for your help